# Django package and app name

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project, that has an app called requests. 
Now I wanted to use OpenID to identify users but the package has dependencies to the package "requests" and I get an error when trying to run my app.

```
from social.utils import setting_name
File "/Users/.../env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/utils.py", line 11, in <module>
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
ImportError: No module named adapters
```

I get that django looks in my requests app for the adapters, which are not there but I don't really get how I can avoid that without renaming my app.

Or even a more general question, is it bad practice or should it be avoided in general to have your own app names the same as packages? Should I check with pip first if there is a package with the name?
I thought within the namespace of my project, I can name my apps as genuine as I wish?

I haven't programmed in ages and just wanted to get back into it a bit by learning python and django.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have app names clashing with names of python packages and django will warn you about that when creating app using `./manage.py startapp`.

It can't be avoided because apps are imported like any other packages.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I renamed the app from request to requests, maybe this is why I didn't get the warning.